# How can I expand collapsed cells in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

There's cells which are filled that have been collapsed or hidden. How can I expand them?

[image]

Comment: This can happen if a filter was applied. If this is the case, changing/removing the filter will also unhide the cells.

Answer (score 2):

Mark the two rows at the top and the bottom of the hidden area (in your example row 95 and 254). After that chose "expand" or "unhide" from the appropriate menu or right click on the selection.

Comment: Although this is technically correct, you may want to specify that the user has to right-click on the separator line/column, or selection.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks for the suggestion, I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your excel sheet, press **Ctrl + A** to select all and go to :
[image]

Comment: This will make everything unhidden. Not sure that's a desired effect.